# brute force string pattern matching average analysis

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have brute force string pattern searching algorithms as  below:

```
public static int brute(String text,String pattern) {
 int n = text.length();    // n is length of text.
 int m = pattern.length(); // m is length of pattern
 int j;
 for(int i=0; i <= (n-m); i++) {
    j = 0;
    while ((j < m) && (text.charAt(i+j) == pattern.charAt(j)) ) {
       j++;
    }
    if (j == m)
     return i;   // match at i
  }
  return -1; // no match
} // end of brute()
```

While anlaysising above algorithm here author mentioned worst case and average case.

I undertstood worst case scenario performance but for average **how author came with O(m+n) performance? Need help here.**

Brute force pattern matching runs in time O(mn) in the worst case.

Average for most searches of ordinary text take O(m+n), which is very quick.

Example of a more average case:
T: "a string searching example is standard"
P: "store"

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What he's referring to with the `O(m+n)` is the partial matches that would happen in the normal case.

For example, with your normal case you will get:

```
T: "a string searching example is standard" 
P: "store"
```

iterations:

```
 O(38 + 5) == 43
 a -     no match (1)
 space - no match (2)
     s     - match (3)
     t     - match (4)
     r     - no match (5)
 t     - no match (6)
 r     - no match (7)
 i     - no match (8)
 n     - no match (9)
 g     - no match (10)
 space     - no match (11)
```

etc...

I indented the inner loop to make it easier to understand.

Eventually you've checked all of `m` which is `O(m)`, but the partial matches mean that you have either checked all of `n` which is `O(n)`(found a complete match), or at least enough charactors to equal the amount of charactors in `n` (partial matches only).

Overall this leads to an `O(m+n)` time on average.

Best case would be `O(n)` if the match is at the very beginning of `m`.

Answer (score 0):

> Brute force pattern matching runs in time O(mn) in the worst case.
>
> Average for most searches of ordinary text take O(m+n), which is very
>   quick.

Note that you can't have 2 Big-O for the same algorithm.

It seems you are applying a brute-force window-shift algorithm,

**Time = (m-n+1)m**

worst case is when you have m=1, **O(nm)**

Best case is when you have m=n, **Ω(m)**

Comment: the question ask explanation for  average case

Comment: Big-O is an upper-bound. The best, worst and average cases can all have upper bounds. So you can use big-O for them. The algorithm itself can also have an upper-bound, which is the same as the worst case.

Comment: Well, The average use (not average case) is where m have Ω(log(n))